# Why is response.xpath('') not printing anything?

Tags: scrapy, cygwin, response, scrapy-shell

I opened a bash prompt using Cygwin on windows 10, I then ran scrapy shell then it looked different before it did not have "in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYYlo.png):"so I am not sure what changed, but then I tried to get a response using XPath, nothing printed and it just went to a new line.

input:

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="pccTableShowDivider"]').get()
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening, if you know why it is now showing the "in[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYYlo.png):" and an explanation for that would also be super helpful.

Sorry if my question was unclear this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Picture of my Code:
[image]

Comment: That is what the ipython shell looks like.... just type `exit` and it will take you back to the bash shell

Comment: What is ipython?

Comment: [ipython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  is a repl/interactive interpreter just like the regular python repl, except it is packed with way more features.  It is also one of the key components of a jupyter notebook

Comment: Your XPath query isn't returning any result because the selector path would be returning nothing. You'd need to provide the webpage on which you are applying this selector to verify if the selector path actually exists.